# How can I put a short-term LGBTQ romance in a restricted environment?

Tags: fantasy, romance, sex, dark-fantasy, lgbt

In my epic fantasy tale, there is a small romantic sideplot. When the main group reaches a kingdom for work, the deutertagonist, while starting off as bitter, begins to develop feelings for the princess. The princess also starts having feelings for the deutertagonist over time, and they start to have a sexual relationship.

There is one problem: The kingdom has homophobic views. It isn't illegal completely, but for details:

- Despite homosexuality being decriminalization and tolerated, it's heavily stigmatized. The princess and deutertagonist may not get executed, but it still results in bad effects.
- The enlightened monarch is hypocritical and has double standards (would be bad when he finds out about his daughter.)

In addition story-wise:

- This small sideplot occurs between 6 months to a year.
- The two characters are supposed to have dislike towards each other, but they eventually warm up.

How could I write the narrative so that, while in a short timespan, it does not feel rushed and/or just unnecessarily placed in for the sake of it?

Comment: Want to know how to write not-quite-accepted gay stuff, go watch Game of Thrones.  They payoff is Season 6, Episode 10, where the new priest is holding a trial accusing various nobility of various "kinky" stuff.

Comment: How is this any different from the king not wanting his daughter to fall in love with a street rat because he is not of noble lineage?   Daddy doesn't want his daughter to date the interesting love interest is a tale as old as time.   There should be plenty of examples where she chooses the "safe" option that isn't the hero of the story.

Comment: @hszmv The king may be what we consider an enlightened monarch, but he is very hypocritical, still keeping his own old religious beliefs despite reforms.

Comment: @Crafter:   Again... that doesn't detract from my comment.   I don't want my daughter dating some one because of stupid reasons.   It's a dime a dozen story.  Find erase the reason and write yours down.   The fact that the daughter is dating another woman doesn't matter any more than the daughter is dating a commoner or daughter is dating a bad boy who wears leather and plays a boom box outside of her window.   Daddy doesn't like his girl dating someone... it's not a new thing.

Comment: @hszmv The era is based on the 16-17th century. Homosexuality may be decriminalized legally, but not by the church or social norms.

Comment: @Crafter:  Again, how does that not comport with my other statements?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing content with style.

*Q: How do I write something that does not feel rushed?*
Take your time writing it. Write it with joy. If you don't enjoy writing it, and aren't super interested in what happens to the characters in that moment, neither will your reader.

*Q: How do I make sure an event doesn't feel unnecessarily placed in for the sake of it?*
Make it necessary; i.e. integral to the story. Part of the characters' arcs, or the story arc; the story would not be the same if that event didn't happen. If that's not the case, cut it.

Also, a bit of unasked-for advice: you might consider a sensitivity read, especially if you're not writing Own Voice.